# Coffeescript, avoid to compile determined rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coffeescript

Is there any way to avoid that Coffeescript compiles few rows? For example, I write a row of code delimited by a special tag and the compiler puts the same row in the compiled file.
I need that because I would try to use the ASP.NET MVC special tag into the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backticks to pass code straight through:

```
coffeeVar = "#{foo}bar"

`var someJs = "this will be passed straight through";`

moreCoffee = (a for a in [1, 2, 3])
```

See CS documentation on [embedded javascript](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded).